# QGIS can output shapefiles larger than 2 GB

Tags: qgis, arcmap, shapefile

I have read that shapefiles are limited to 2 GB, yet I have found that QGIS can go beyond that limit. In this case, I was generating contours from DEMs. The output would have been greater than 2 GB, and ArcMap failed, but QGIS created the output. Has anyone else noticed this? Just curious…

Comment: Yes, QGIS generates non-conformant "shapefiles". File geodatabase would use a fraction of the size, *and* not be restricted to an early 1990s limitation.

Comment: QGIS uses GDAL Shapefile driver which can exceed this limit, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312396/107424

Comment: Thanks, all. After further processing (simplifying, etc.) I may get to below 2 GB, but if I don’t I’ll go the route of a FGDB. (I’d go with GPKG if I could but I operate in an Esri-centric universe.)